# Jenkins Robot Framework Performance Trending Graph

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, robotframework

Working with jenkins where my robot framework test is measuring some kind of performance and receiving an integer as a test result.
Looking for a way how I can add to existing trending graphs of successful tests and tests duration, additional graph that will show the performance (test result) for different builds in a graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write this number into a file, you can use Jenkins [Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) to graph values.

Comment: I can write the results to file, but hot the Plot Plugin will know to go thru all my previous builds and get the files with the actual result from those files?